# JXCollapsiblePane with JXMultiSplitPane

Tags: java, swingx, collapsable

I have a user interface that uses a JXMultiSplitPane to display multiple components. However, I would like some of the panes to be collapsible. I thought about how I might use a JXCollapsiblePane here, but I can't figure out a good way to have the multisplit and collapsibility of select panes.

My thought was to not use JXCollapsible pane but rather to just create a button that collapses/expands a pane by setting the divider location for that pane. Would there a way to use JXCollapsiblePane here so I can get the nice features such as the animated collapsing/expanding?

Answer (score 1):

```
        multiSplitPane.getMultiSplitLayout().displayNode("r0", !hide);
```

Use displayNode() to show/hide specific panes.